# How can i run my scenario with chrome using junit4 and selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, junit4

In 2 days ago a was used this scenario and it works but know all time she didn't I don't know why, I use Selenium webdriver and junit4 
so this my scenario and how i run chrome-driver with cmd and the error

```
package com.example.test;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
public class SearchWithCH {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
  @Test
  public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/myapp/pages/accueil/login.xhtml#loaded");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("login");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainMenu']/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu_contact_search']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("formRecherche:nom")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("formRecherche:nom")).sendKeys("Jean");
    driver.findElement(By.id("formRecherche:button_recherche")).click();
    try {
      assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='panel_contact_id_header']/span")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Contact : 9673 [\\s\\S]*$"));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
  }
  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }
}
```

and i was run chrome driver with

```
> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Projet\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0\chromedriver.exe
```

but i have this error

```
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
Command duration or timeout: 130 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.30.0', revision: 'dc1ef9c', time: '2013-02-19 00:15:57'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_13'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at com.QD2.Search.SearchWithCH.setUp(SearchWithCH.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.callConstructor(DefaultDriverFactory.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First start selenium server with below command

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=latest\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar
```

And then use below logic to create chrome driver instance

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\selenium\\latest\\chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setBrowserName("chrome");
driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),dc);
```

And run your test case using **driver** instance

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: today i re-run my scenario but she didn't work :/
and i have the same error.
I use selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar

Comment: just verify chromedriver.exe path .

Answer (score 1):

try adding to the code **before** you initialize the Chromedriver:

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\Projet\\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0\\chromedriver.exe");
```

**EDIT**
Regarding your comments. Try this:

- Press Ctrl + Alt + Del
- Choose Task Manager
- Switch to Processes
- Sort by Name
- Kill **all** "chromedriver" processes
- Optionally: Restart computer
- Try again

BTW, do you have Chrome installed?

**EDIT2**
Now I realised, that you are using RemoteWebDriver! So you have to start hub and node like this:

1st the hub:

```
 java -jar lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role hub
```

2nd the node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 15 -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=15 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Projet\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0\chromedriver.exe
```

And then run your test

Comment: stupid question then - is at the path really stored the chromedriver.exe?

Comment: yes C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Projet\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0\chromedriver.exe is th path to chromedriver

Comment: go to Start - Run, type cmd. Here you type `cd C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Projet\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0` and then type chromedriver.exe - you should see some output...

Comment: Started ChromeDriver
port=9515
version=26.0.1383.0

Comment: In that case try to go to http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list and download the latest chromedriver and replace that one which you have right now - you are doing everything as I am doing in my tests and its working for me...

Comment: I have th last chromedriver and i re downlowad and replace it but i have the same error :/

Comment: Then I am really hopeless. You do everything as I do. And yes, it works for me...

Comment: Wait a second! You use remote webdriver! Please update the question and show me how do you initialize the hub and node...

Comment: it works for me too in 2 day ago but know i dont know why she didn't work

Comment: i use the 2 methods But :/ the same erroe :'(

Comment: is the hub and node running on the same machine?

Comment: Yes it run in th same machine